# Pinescript Strategy Delay

Tags: pine-script

[Tradingview Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAtRp.png)
So, here's the deal: I've developed a strategy that hinges on the concept of divergences for market entries. The interesting thing is that this strategy involves identifying divergences and marking them on the indicator chart. However, what's puzzling is that even though the divergences are identified early on, the actual entry into the market doesn't occur until several candles have passed. It's this delay that's got me a bit perplexed.

To elaborate further, my strategy revolves around pinpointing instances where the price action and the indicator move in opposite directions. These divergences often indicate potential turning points in the market. So, I've set up my system to visually highlight these divergences on the indicator chart as soon as they emerge. But here's the catch: the strategy doesn't execute trades immediately after a divergence is spotted. Instead, there seems to be a deliberate waiting period spanning several candlesticks before any actual trading activity takes place.

The confusion stems from the rationale behind this delay. Why does my strategy hold off on entering the market despite identifying what seems to be a promising setup? Is there a specific logic or market behavior that drives this waiting period? These are the questions that I'm currently grappling with. Understanding this delay could potentially shed light on the underlying dynamics of the strategy and its effectiveness. As I delve deeper into the intricacies of this approach, unraveling the mystery behind the timing of market entries becomes a crucial aspect of refining and fine-tuning the strategy for optimal results.

```
maType = input.string(title='Moving Average Type', options=['DPO', 'Momentum', 'MACD', 'RSI', 'Stoch'], defval='DPO')
len = input.int(title='LookBack Period', minval=1, defval=117)
lbR = input(title='Pivot Lookback Right', defval=5)
lbL = input.int(title='Pivot Lookback Left', defval=5, maxval=21)
rangeUpper = input(title='Max of Lookback Range', defval=500)
rangeLower = input(title='Min of Lookback Range', defval=7)
plotBull = input(title='Plot Bullish', defval=true)
plotHiddenBull = input(title='Plot Hidden Bullish', defval=true)
plotBear = input(title='Plot Bearish', defval=true)
plotHiddenBear = input(title='Plot Hidden Bearish', defval=true)

bearColor = color.red
bullColor = color.green
hiddenBullColor = color.new(color.yellow, 70)
hiddenBearColor = color.new(color.orange, 70)
textColor = color.white
noneColor = color.new(color.white, 100)



plFound = na(ta.pivotlow(mom, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
phFound = na(ta.pivothigh(mom, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true

_inRange(cond) =>
    bars = ta.barssince(cond == true)
    rangeLower <= bars and bars <= rangeUpper










//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regular Bullish

// Osc: Higher Low
oscHL = mom[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, mom[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

// Price: Lower Low
priceLL = low[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)

bullCond = plotBull and priceLL and oscHL and plFound

plot(plFound ? mom[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Regular Bullish', linewidth=2, color=bullCond ? bullColor : noneColor)

plotshape(bullCond ? mom[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Regular Bullish Label', text=' Bull ', style=shape.labelup, location=location.bottom, color=color.new(bullColor, 0), size=size.small, textcolor=color.new(textColor, 0))

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Hidden Bullish

// Osc: Lower Low
oscLL = mom[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, mom[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

// Price: Higher Low
priceHL = low[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)

hiddenBullCond = plotHiddenBull and priceHL and oscLL and plFound

plot(plFound ? mom[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Hidden Bullish', linewidth=2, color=hiddenBullCond ? hiddenBullColor : noneColor)

plotshape(hiddenBullCond ? mom[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Hidden Bullish Label', text=' H Bull ', style=shape.labelup, location=location.bottom, color=hiddenBullColor, size=size.small, textcolor=color.new(textColor, 0))

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regular Bearish

// Osc: Lower High
oscLH = mom[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(phFound, mom[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])

// Price: Higher High
priceHH = high[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)

bearCond = plotBear and priceHH and oscLH and phFound

plot(phFound ? mom[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Regular Bearish', linewidth=2, color=bearCond ? bearColor : noneColor)

plotshape(bearCond ? mom[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Regular Bearish Label', text=' Bear ', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.top, color=color.new(bearColor, 0), size=size.small, textcolor=color.new(textColor, 0))

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Hidden Bearish

// Osc: Higher High
oscHH = mom[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(phFound, mom[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])

// Price: Lower High
priceLH = high[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)

hiddenBearCond = plotHiddenBear and priceLH and oscHH and phFound

plot(phFound ? mom[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Hidden Bearish', linewidth=2, color=hiddenBearCond ? hiddenBearColor : noneColor)

plotshape(hiddenBearCond ? mom[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Hidden Bearish Label', text=' H Bear ', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.top, color=hiddenBearColor, size=size.tiny, textcolor=color.new(textColor, 0))

bull = bullCond[lbR]  or hiddenBullCond[lbR]
bear = bearCond[lbR]  or hiddenBearCond[lbR]

tp = input(110,"tp1")
sl = input(1000,"sl1")

longCondition = bull
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Calls", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("TP1", from_entry="Calls", qty_percent = 100, profit = tp, loss = sl)



shortCondition = bear
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Puts", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("TP1", from_entry="Puts", qty_percent = 100, profit = tp, loss = sl)
```

I tried manipulating the look back ranges but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how divergences work. In order to find divergences, your code first finds the pivot points with `ta.pivotlow()` and `ta.pivothigh()`.

```
ta.pivothigh(source, leftbars, rightbars) → series float
```

You can only find a pivot point after some bars formed. That is the `rightbars` argument for you. In your case it is `lbR`.

What it tells you is, it will wait for `lbR` number of bars to see if there was a pivot point. This delay comes from the fact that you cannot know if the current bar is a pivot bar or not. You need to wait for some time and look back to see how the price moved and confirm a potential pivot point.

Your plots also use `offset`.

```
plotshape(bullCond ? mom[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Regular Bullish Label', text=' Bull ', style=shape.labelup, location=location.bottom, color=color.new(bullColor, 0), size=size.small, textcolor=color.new(textColor, 0))
```

`offset=-lbR`

This is why you think it identifies the divergence instantly. What really happens is, it finds the pivot (that happened in the past) and moves your `plotshape` to there using the offset. If you notice, the offset is also set to  `lbR`.

You can see this more clearly if you use the bar replay function.